# Iterating though an array of structs in C

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, pointer-arithmetic

Can someone explain this for loop to me?

```
struct {
  int lock;   // not used in Lab
  struct proc proc[NPROC];
} ptable;

void scheduler(void){
struct proc *p;

  acquire(&ptable.lock);
  for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
    if(p == curr_proc || p->state != RUNNABLE)
      continue;

    // Switch to chosen process.
    curr_proc = p;
    p->state = RUNNING;
    break;
  }
  release(&ptable.lock);

}
```

Mostly I'm asking about the for loop

```
  for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
```

What does assigning the pointer p to ptable.proc do? And how do I access the struct proc's members/variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay)

Comment: What Stephen Newell said. And you access struct proc's variables like you actually do in your code: p->state.

Comment: When a `for` loop is hard to undestand, writing it as a `while` loop may make understanding easier.

Comment: `What does assigning the pointer p to ptable.proc do?`. It makes `p` point to `ptable.proc`.  IOW, the value of `p` is now the address of `ptable.proc[0]`.  Incrementing `p` makes the value of `p` be the address of `ptable.proc[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mostly I'm asking about the for loop
>
> ```c
> for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
> ```

```c
p = ptable.proc
```

Here the array `ptable.proc` decays into a pointer to the first element in the array and `p` is assigned this pointer. It's the same as doing `p = &ptable.proc[0]`.

```c
p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]
```

Here `p` is compared with the address one element outside the array bounds (out of bounds). `ptable.proc[NPROC - 1]` is the last element within bounds.

```c
p++
```

This steps the pointer to point at the next `struct proc` in the `struct proc` array.

So, the `for`-loop as a whole starts by making `p` point at the first `struct proc` in the array and iterates through all the elements in the array until `p` points outside the array, then it terminates the loop.

Here's an alternative loop with the same result to visualize what's going on:

```c
// for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
for(int idx = 0; idx < NPROC; idx++) {
    p = &ptable.proc[idx];   // or:   p = ptable.proc + idx;

    // the rest of the loop body goes here ...
}
```

> And how do I access the struct proc's members/variables?

You dereference the pointer `p` with the `->` operator to access the members of the element `p` is pointing at. `p->state` accesses the `state` member in the `struct proc` that `p` is currently pointing at.

Answer (score 1):

`p = ptable.proc` assigns a pointer to the start of the array to `p`.

The array contains `NPROC` elements so `&ptable.proc[NPROC]` is the (notional) address of one past the last element (`ptable.proc[NPROC-1]` is the last element). `ptable.proc+NPROC` would be cleaner.

`p++` increments the pointer by the size of one `struct proc`.

The net effect is a pointer starts at the beginning of the array a progress up through it moving `sizeof(struct proc)` bytes each time visiting each element of the array until it passes the end and immediately stops.

It may look complicated but in C it is the most efficient and natural way to iterate through an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array as for example like

```
enum { N = 10 };
int a[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

then you can access its elements using the subscript operator like for example

```
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf( "%d ", a[i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

The subscript operator is evaluated like

```
a[i] ==> *( a + i )
```

But if you have a pointer to the i-th element of the array like

```
int *p = &a[i];
```

then instead of the expression `a[i]` you can just use the expression `*p` to get the value of the i-th element of the array.

Initially you can initialize the pointer `p` by the address of the first element of the array

```
int *p = &a[0];
```

that is equivalent to

```
int *p = a;
```

because in this case the array is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

So the expression `*p` yields the first element `a[0]` of the array. To output the second element of the array you could write for example `p[1]` that is equivalent to `*( p + 1 )`.

But the expression `p + 1` yields the same value as the expression `++p` because the expression `++p` is evaluated like `p = p + 1`.

So you can write to output the first element of the array

```
printf( "%d ", *p );
```

To output the second element of the array you could write

```
printf( "%d ", *++p );
```

or

```
++p;
printf( "%d ", *p );
```

and so on.

Thus the above for loop can be rewritten using a pointer the following way

```
for ( int *p = a; p < a + N; ++p )
{
    printf( "%d ", *p );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```